# Do not display the "Serial upvoting reversed" message with zero points

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, reputation-history

I get a "Serial upvoting reversed" message with zero points total:

[image: Serial upvoting reversed image]

Since the record does not convey any useful information, couldn't it be dropped from view?

Comment: I think it's useful. Votes were reversed and rep was not affected.

Comment: @Mysticial If a tree falls in the forest and no one is around to hear it does it make a sound?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Of course. By definition falling trees make noises. You can tell by all the traumatized squirrels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume what happened here is that the serial upvotes were cast *after* you had reached the reputation cap for that day. Thus, you hadn't earned any reputation from them, and you didn't lose any when they were removed.

I don't think this information should be removed altogether. It does still tell you something useful, and leaving it visible is consistent with the display of upvotes received after you've hit the rep cap. It's not like it's adding needless clutter—you have to go into the detailed "reputation" view before you even see it.

Possibly the presentation of it in the UI could be improved and/or made to convey a bit more information.

Comment: I thought of a similarity to the capped upvotes too, but I think they do give you some information, because they tell you what question has been upvoted after the cap. The removal notice, on the other hand, does not even tell you on what day the serial upvoting has happened, let alone the questions or answers the votes on which have been reversed. Essentially, it tells you that a maintenance algorithm ran in the background, and performed some cleanup.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Just because you don't find that information useful at all doesn't mean other people wouldn't. Generally the serial voting script only runs at 03:00 and would affect a string of votes that occurred the day before. It's a simple confirmation to a user that "yes, that string of votes that occurred yesterday got invalidated." The only other time that message would really appear is if a dev invalidated votes manually.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, The serial upvotes would have to have happened in the last day, as the script in question runs once every 24hrs.

Comment: @animuson My assumption was that the script is an implementation detail of the site, and that it is a good thing to keep it private to the site when possible. However, I do see your point that this message would be valuable to users who noticed a serial voting pattern in their accounts a day earlier.